# How to send image as body content in mail - Android

Tags: android

I am using below code but this sends the mail but image does not appear shows dots. Image replaced with dots.

And I want to display image in mail body.

```
String body="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><img src=\""+Param.baseURL+mMessage.getMessages().get(position).getListPicture()+"\" style=width:100px;height:100px>" +
                          "<p>"+mMessage.getMessages().get(position).getText()+"</p></body></html>";
```

Above html works well in html file but while sending in email this display image in dots.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");           
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testemail");    
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please adapt your question. You are not trying to send an image as body content for a html mail. Instead in the html source you just have an img tag with a src attribute which you want to point to an image on your server. Better show the url you have put in the src attribute. You just use the wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this with Intents.**

The reason why for example bold text is displayed in the EditText and not an Image is that StyleSplan is implementing Parcelable whereas ImageSpan does not. So when the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is retrieved in the new Activity the ImageSpan will fail to unparcel and therefor not be part of the style appended to the EditText.

Using other methods where you don't pass the data with the Intent is unfortunately not possible here as you're not in control of the receiving Activity.

But What you can do is attach an image with the mail

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

where uri is a file path URI.

Comment: Yes. uri is a image path which is uploaded on server.

Answer (score 0):

try like this may help you,

String htmlString = "";

```
String mailId="yourmail@gmail.com";
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, 
                                Uri.fromParts("mailto",mailId, null)); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject text here"); 
// you can use simple text like this
// emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Body text here"); 
// or get fancy with HTML like this
emailIntent.putExtra(
         Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
         Html.fromHtml(htmlString)
         );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: Image is uploaded on server and I have url.

Comment: :-) This is hilarious.